# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: flutter, gradle, geolocation, build.gradle, flutter-dependencies

I have am getting the following error:

```
    An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.8.0_242-release). Please file a bug against the Java compiler via the Java bug reporting page (http://bugreport.java.com) after checking the Bug Database (http://bugs.java.com) for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report. Thank you.
        java.lang.AssertionError: annotationType(): unrecognized Attribute name MODULE (class com.sun.tools.javac.util.UnsharedNameTable$NameImpl)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.util.Assert.error(Assert.java:133)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations.annotationType(TypeAnnotations.java:231)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.separateAnnotationsKinds(TypeAnnotations.java:294)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitVarDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1164)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCVariableDecl.accept(JCTree.java:852)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:57)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.visitClassDef(TypeAnnotations.java:1042)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:693)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:49)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$TypeAnnotationPositions.scan(TypeAnnotations.java:275)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.code.TypeAnnotations$1.run(TypeAnnotations.java:127)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Annotate.flush(Annotate.java:152))
            at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:857)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
            at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.call(ResourceCleaningCompilationTask.java:57)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:50)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:100)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.execute(AnnotationProcessorDiscoveringCompiler.java:51)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilerFactory$2.execute(IncrementalCompilerFactory.java:110)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:59)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler$2.call(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
            at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.execute(CompileJavaBuildOperationReportingCompiler.java:51)
            at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:154)
            at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:122)
            at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.kt:237)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
            at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.java:46)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
            at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
            at 
            at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
            at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
            at readRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
        
        * What went wrong:
        Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

by using :

```
geolocator : 7.0.3 and 8.0.5
```

I have tried geolocator: 6.0.2
It shows error of geocoding depends upon gelocator >=6.0.2 <7.0.0
I also have tried all verisons of

```
compiledsdk:28,29,31
minsdk:20
targetsdk:28,29,30,31
```

On changing the compiledsdk versions it shows "Gradle reimport failed"